# Find custom near locations

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a table with the following fields:
Name Longitude Latitude

The user can search for near places depending on the radius he chooses, what is the algorithm used to do this?

Example: I retrieve the user Longitude/Latitude, and I ask him about the radius in KM he wants to apply to his search, then these 3 parameters should be sent to the method that will retrieve the location.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
In other words what we need is the distance between two points that we have their coordinates, so using math :

[Distance between two points](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php)